# consuming SharePoint 2010 web service from asp.net(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I use web services quite often, but mainly from standalone (console) applications or JS, but now I need to consume SharePoint 2010 web service (`Lists.asmx`) from an ASP.NET(VB) page...

I'm editing aspx page in Visual Studio 2010, already added web reference to WS (VS created those `.discomap`, `.disco` and `.wsdl` files in `App_WebReferences` folder). In code file for my page I've imported WS namespace at the top of the file and VS successfully hints me all WS methods and so on.

But when I save the file and try to open it from web browser, IIS server shouts that it don't know WS namespace!? (Compiler Error Message: `BC30002: Type 'wsIntranet.Lists' is not defined.`)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks. #JK

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports wsIntranet


Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim ws As wsIntranet.Lists = New wsIntranet.Lists



    End Sub
End Class
```

[VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijs6b.png)

[IIS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Im6t.png)

edit:
I'm confused... I just found out that it is really possible to use reference to .svc web service (`http://intranet/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`) in standalone (.exe) application (it is new for me, thanks for that info), but it seems to be unable to use it in case of editing ASP page in VS.

In Visual Studio I can only add web reference to .asmx web service (`http://intranet/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`) and VS generates neccessary files to be able imports WS namespace and use it for communication with WS.

What Im doing is (all in VS ):

1. File > Open Web Site > select my ASP site and page
2. right click over Web Site Properties and select > Add Web Reference > choose URL "`http://intranet/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`", change Web reference name to "wsIntranet" and click button Add Reference (then VS generates those files
3. I can use new class in code file like (and I can see all its properties, methods and so on in Object Browser):
   Imports wsIntranet
   Dim ws As wsIntranet.Lists = New wsIntranet.Lists

But then, when I save the code file and trying to open that web site from web browser I get Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'wsIntranet.Lists' is not defined
...???

Comment: 1) Where did you find the `Lists` type? I'm certain the proxy generator *didn't* generate anything like that. It creates a client class that typically ends with `Client`. 2) 2010 uses WCF and OData. `Lists.asmx` are left over from 2007. It's not a good idea to use the asmx services.

Comment: Huh, I use asmx web services all the time and never thought, that there could be another alternative...!? See oficial MSDN page for WebSvcLists: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists(v=office.14).aspx